# A command-line utility to solve a system of linear equations

Tags: python, python-2.x, numpy

I was re-checking my answers for a Math paper on my laptop. I needed to verify my solution for a system of linear equations. Unfortunately, I found no quick way to do that. That's why I wrote a (hopefully) simple Python program (using NumPy) to do this job quickly. General comments on the code are appreciated.

**linearsolver.py**

```
from sys import argv, exit
from fractions import Fraction
import numpy as np
import string


def solve(A, B, vars=['x', 'y']):
    X = np.linalg.inv(A) * B.transpose()
    values = []
    for item in X:
        values.append(Fraction(item[0, 0]).limit_denominator())
    return dict(zip(vars, values))


def vars(len):
    alph = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    # x is the 24th alphabet
    start = 23 if len <= 3 else 0
    return list(alph[start:start + len])


def interact():
    print "======================\nLinear Equation Solver\n======================\nHow many equations (and variables) ? ",

    len = int(raw_input())

    # Input the variable names
    vars = []
    print "Enter the variables involved :"
    for i in range(0, len):
        vars.append(raw_input())

    # Input the coefficients
    a = []
    print "Enter the coefficients of the variables in order, for each equation:"
    for i in range(1, len + 1):
        print "-----%d-----" % i
        temp = []
        for i in range(0, len):
            temp.append(float(raw_input()))
        a.append(temp)

    # Input the values they equal to
    print "Enter the constants for the RHS :"
    b = []
    for i in range(0, len):
        b.append(float(raw_input()))

    A = np.matrix(a)
    B = np.matrix(b)
    answer = solve(A, B, vars)
    print_answer(answer)


def print_answer(answer):
    for variable, value in answer.items():
        print "%4s = %4s" % (variable, value)


def main(argv):
    num = len(argv)
    varlist = None
    if num == 1:
        # Only the script name: enter interactive mode
        interact()
        exit()
    elif num == 3:
        script, a, b = argv
    elif num == 4:
        script, a, varlist, b = argv
    else:
        print "Too many arguments."
        sys.exit()

    A = np.matrix(a)
    B = np.matrix(b)

    rows = A.shape[0]
    cols = A.shape[1]

    if rows != cols:
        print "Number of rows must be equal to number of columns."
        exit()

    if varlist is None:
        answer = solve(A, B, vars(rows))
    else:
        answer = solve(A, B, list(varlist))
    print_answer(answer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(argv)
```

Some example runs:

```
$ python linearsolver.py "2 5 -9 3; 5 6 -4 2; 3 -4 2 7; 11 7 4 -8" "151 103 16 -32"
   a =    3
   c =  -11
   b =    5
   d =    7
$ python linearsolver.py "5 -11 9; 13 7 -10; -6 5 -8" "gkm" "-125 2 60"
   k =   12
   m =    3
   g =   -4
$ python linearsolver.py
======================
Linear Equation Solver
======================
How many equations (and variables) ?  7
Enter the variables involved :
s
t
u
v
w
x
y
Enter the coefficients of the variables in order, for each equation:
-----1-----
2
-7
3
5
-7
11
8
-----2-----
5
7
-1
9
-6
3
-5
-----3-----
13
11
8
7
4
2
1
-----4-----
12
1
6
5
9
3
11
-----5-----
1
-4
7
-3
9
-2
6
-----6-----
4
1
-6
-3
8
-7
-4
-----7-----
-7
-2
5
1
9
3
-4
Enter the constants for the RHS :
114
-11
-25
-37
4
-91
-50
   s =    5
   u =    8
   t =   -7
   w =   -9
   v =   -6
   y =   -3
   x =    2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### List comprehensions

List comprehensions are a cool feature that could shorten your code, at many places.
For example instead of this:

> ```
>     values = []
>     for item in X:
>         values.append(Fraction(item[0, 0]).limit_denominator())
> ```

You can write like this:

```
    values = [Fraction(item[0, 0]).limit_denominator() for item in X]
```

Another example:

> ```
>     vars = []
>     for i in range(0, len):
>         vars.append(raw_input())
> ```

Better this way:

```
    vars = [raw_input() for _ in range(len)]
```

There are some more tips in there:

- `range(len)` is equivalent to `range(0, len)`
- When you don't use the loop variable in the loop body, the convention is to name the loop variable `_`

There are other places in your code that you could shorten using list comprehensions, I suggest to rewrite them all.

#### Magic values

The number 23 is a magic value here:

> ```
>     # x is the 24th alphabet
>     start = 23 if len <= 3 else 0
> ```

Although the comment explains it, it would be better to put the value in a constant with a name that describes its purpose.
And instead of the hard-coded number, I suggest to express it in a programmatic way, for example:

```
POS_X = ord('x') - ord('a')
```

When written this way, we don't even have to know what the value really is (23), the important thing is its relative position from the letter 'a'.

#### Code duplication

The `solve` calls are duplicated here, except for the 3rd parameter:

> ```
>     if varlist is None:
>         answer = solve(A, B, vars(rows))
>     else:
>         answer = solve(A, B, list(varlist))
>     print_answer(answer)
> ```

It would be better to reorganize the code to eliminate such duplication:

```
    if varlist is None:
        varlist = vars(rows)

    answer = solve(A, B, varlist)
    print_answer(answer)
```

Of course, in your current implementation `varlist` is not really a list.
It would be better to fix that, and make it a list when you assign it earlier, for example:

```
elif num == 4:
    script, a, symbols, b = argv
    varlist = list(symbols)
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to use nested list comprehension?

Comment: If it doesn't hurt readability, then yes. Otherwise no. No need to force the list comprehensions, but in the examples I gave it's easy to see to agree that it's an improvement. When it becomes questionable, then it's probably better to use a good old-fashioned loop.

Answer (score 2):

Just looking at the `solve` function:

1. There's no docstring. What does this function do? What are the constraints on the inputs? What does it return?
2. `B.transpose()` can be written [`B.T`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html).
3. The function relies on its inputs being `np.matrix` objects, so that the `*` operation is matrix multiplication (rather than element-wise multiplication). But this makes the function awkward to use — normally when working with NumPy you have array objects, not matrices, and so you have to remember to convert them to matrices whenever you called the function.

   Although this isn't a problem here, it's the kind of thing that becomes a pain later on, and so I recommend that even in simple programs like this, you stick to `np.array` (avoiding `np.matrix`), and when you need to compute a matrix multiplication, you use the [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) function. (Or, in Python 3.5 or later, the new `@` operator.)
4. Instead of:

   ```
   X = np.linalg.inv(A) * B.transpose()
   ```

   use [`np.linalg.solve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html), like this:

   ```
   X = np.linalg.solve(A, B.T)
   ```

   (Or `np.linalg.solve(A, B)` if you are using `np.array` as recommended above.)

   The reason for doing this is that computing the inverse of a matrix requires more computation than solving a system of linear equations, and so can result in larger errors due to making more floating-point approximations.
5. The `vars` argument has a default value of `['x', 'y']` but this only works if `A` is a 2×2 matrix. It would be better if the default value for `vars` supplied as many variables as needed. This could be implemented using an generator that yielded an unbounded sequence of variable names (see the function `variable_names` below).
6. The [`limit_denominator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator) method takes an argument `max_denominator` which the user of `solve` might want to change. It would make sense to add it as a keyword argument to the `solve` function.

Revised code (using `np.array` and not `np.matrix` as recommended in point 3 above):

```
from fractions import Fraction
from itertools import count, product
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_lowercase

def variable_names():
    """Generate variable names a, b, ..., z, a', b', ..., z', a'', ..."""
    for primes in count():
        for letter in ascii_lowercase:
            yield letter + "'" * primes

def solve(A, B, vars=None, max_denominator=1000000):
    """Solve the system of linear equations A @ vars = B.

    Arguments:
    A -- array with shape (m, m)
    B -- array with shape (m)
    vars -- iterable of variable names. If omitted,
        variable_names() is used.
    max_denominator -- values in solution are converted to fractions
        with denominator at most this.

    Returns: dictionary mapping variable names to their values.

    """
    X = np.linalg.solve(A, B)
    values = [Fraction(i).limit_denominator(max_denominator) for i in X]
    if vars is None:
        vars = variable_names()
    return dict(zip(vars, values))
```

Comment: I really like this version better. :-) BTW... What if I want to use x, y and z if I need 3 variables? How do you suggest one should do it?

Comment: If you want the variable names to start with `x`, then write `'xyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw'` (or whatever order you prefer) instead of `ascii_lowercase`.

Comment: Well... I want to start with `x` only when I need 3 or less. The rest of the time... I'm happy to start from `a`.